# MinGW fprintf (vswprintf) causing a segmentation fault

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

I have the following example program that uses the preprocessor to define a simple debug function.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef DEBUG
#define __DEBUG 1
#else
#define __DEBUG 0
#endif
#define dbg_out(fmt, ...) \
    do {if (__DEBUG) fprintf(stdout, "%s:%s:%s():" fmt "\n", __FILE__, \
                           __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__); } while (0)

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    dbg_out ("Printing argc: %d", argc);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with debug symbols and DEBUG defined, like so:

`gcc main.c -g -DDEBUG -o test.exe`

Now, when I compile this program and run it, I get a `SIGSEGV` with the following backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x75b7b090 in vswprintf () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll

(gdb) bt

#0  0x75b7b090 in vswprintf () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
#1  0x75b73633 in msvcrt!fprintf () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
#2  0x75bb1228 in msvcrt!_iob () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
#3  0x0040a070 in __register_frame_info ()
#4  0x00401425 in main (argc=1, argv=0x4a2f08) at src/main.c:16
```

GCC (MinGW) version is `4.8.1`. Why is this crash occurring? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessor macro `__LINE__` is not a `char *`, it's an `int`, so:

```
#define dbg_out(fmt, ...) \
    do {if (__DEBUG) fprintf(stdout, "%s:%s:%s():" fmt "\n", __FILE__, \
                           __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__); } while (0)
```

needs to be:

```
#define dbg_out(fmt, ...) \
    do {if (__DEBUG) fprintf(stdout, "%s:%d:%s():" fmt "\n", __FILE__, \
                           __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__); } while (0)
```

Note that `gcc` would have warned you about this if were compiling with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`).

Comment: Yeah, I did use `-Wall` in my larger project, but I had many unused variable errors so I missed it. When I made this test case I totally forgot about it. I'll keep it in mind for the future. Such a simple mistake, yet sometimes so hard to notice. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's why it's important to always fix warnings and "compile clean" - although many warnings may well be harmless (e.g. unused variables) the noise from these harmless warnings may cause you to miss something important.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please refer the following code.

    #include <stdio.h>
#define DEBUG 1
#ifdef DEBUG
#define __DEBUG 1
#else
#define __DEBUG 0
#endif
#define dbg_out(fmt, ...) \
    do {if (__DEBUG) fprintf(stdout, "%s:%d:%s():" fmt "\n", __FILE__, \
                           __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__); } while (0)

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    dbg_out ("Printing argc: %d", argc);
    return 0;
}
~
```

~

Comment: why someone has given -1 point? See the time difference between my post and prev post. I did not noticed the above solution.

Comment: Answer was down-voted for low quality: (a) no explanation, (b) redundant code included, (c) messy formatting, (d) essentially the same as an existing answer.

Comment: So you also down voted without providing any reason. And there was only one mistake by the author, so I thought he can understand it. Though the standard of question is also very low.